# not sure why I'm getting "Attempt to modify property of non-object in"

Tags: php, arrays, containers

I am writing an function that feeds information into a container class. I keep getting the error `Attempt to modify property of non-object in`. There are a lot of classes involved and I can upload the entire project if someone was willing to look at it in total. All of the individual classes have been tested for functionality and performs as expected, it's just assign the values in the new class through this function that is giving the error. I have attached the container class and the function which resides in another class here.  Thanks so much for your help!

```
class masterContainer{
    public $mc = array('file','line' => array('line' => array('string','element'=>array())));//this array stores all the contents needed for a file
    public function __construct($file){
        $this->file = $file;
        $this->mc['file'] = $this->file;
        $mc['line'] = array();
        $mc['line'][$l]['string'] = $line[$l];
        $mc['line'][$l]['element'] = array();
        $mc['line'][$l]['element'] = $element[$e];
    }//end __construct()
}//end masterContainer{}
```

this is the function

```
<?php
require_once('/Library/WebServer/Documents/gasDev/super_src/controller/fileController.php');
require_once('/Library/WebServer/Documents/gasDev/super_src/container/masterContainer.php');
require_once('/Library/WebServer/Documents/gasDev/super_src/controller/lineController.php');
require_once('/Library/WebServer/Documents/gasDev/super_src/controller/elementController.php');

class masterControl{

public $fc;//fileHandling
public $container;////masterContainer
public $lc;//lineController
public $ec;//elementController


public function __construct($path){
    $this->buildContainer($path);

}//end __construct()

public function buildContainer($path)
{
    $this->fc = new fileController($path);//create files
    foreach($this->fc->getFiles() as $f){$this->container[] = new masterContainer($f);};//create containers, assign file to memory
//      foreach($this->container as $c){echo $c->file."<br>";};//lists all files in container
    $i=0;//a counter
    foreach($this->container as $c){$this->lc[] = new lineController($c->file);$i++;};//create new lines
//assign lines to memory
    $i=0;//a counter
    foreach($this->lc as $line){
        $j=0;//a counter
        //echo $i."<br>";
        foreach($line->getLines() as $l){
            $this->container[$i]->line[$j] = $l;
            //echo $l."<br>";
            $j++;
        };//assign line to memory
        //echo "<br>";
        $i++;
    };


//make elements
$i=0;
foreach($this->container as $c){
    //echo count($c->line)."<br>";
    //echo "=-".$i."-=<br>";
    $j=0;
    foreach($c->line as $l){
        //echo $i." - ".$l."<br>";
        $this->ec[] = new elementController("*",$l);

        foreach($this->ec as $elements){
            $k=0;
            foreach($elements->getElements() as $e){
                //echo $e."<br>";
                $this->container[$i]->line[$j]->element[$k] = $e;
                //echo $k."<br>";
                $k++;
            };
        };
        //echo "__".$j."__<br>";
        $j++;
    };
    $i++;
};
//      echo "<br><br>";
//      echo "file: ".$this->container[0]->file."<br><br>";
//      echo "line: ".$this->container[0]->line[0]."<br>";
//      echo "element: ".$this->container[0]->line[0]->element[0]."<br>";
}//end buildContainer()

public function echoArray($array){foreach ($array as $a){echo $a."<br>";};}
public function __toString(){}

}//end mastController{}
$mc = new masterControl('/Library/WebServer/Documents/gasDev/test_files/850_855_csv_tests/850');
?>
```

Comment: What line does it say the error is occurring in?

Comment: $this->container[$i]->line[$j]->element[$k] = $e;//assign element to memory on this line it's 9 from the bottom.  I added a comment right before it

Comment: Based on your other comments it would look like `line[$j]` is not getting instantiated (or it was and wasn't properly assigned).  What do you get if you run `var_dump($this->container[$i]->line[$j])`?  If it isn't the object you are expecting, that would be where to start working backwards from.

Comment: I added the entire class that the function resides in

Comment: @Crackertatstic - I get what I expect out of `var_dump($this->container[$i]->line[$j])` It's when I try to add to $this->container[$i]->line[$j]->element[] that I get the error

Comment: cant see any defined `line` or `element` property. You kill yourself with this code.

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->container
```

is undefined and should be initialized as an array.

Or:

```
$this->container[$i]->line[$j]->element[$k]
```

line or element are not initialized.

It really hard to debug such code...

Comment: I can assign to $this->container[]->file, as well as to $this->container[]->line[] but when I try to assign to $this->container[]->line[]->element[] i get the error

Comment: Sorry for the difficulty, I added the entire class if it helps.  Thanks for the feed back. I'm pretty sure `$this->container[$i]->line[$j]->element[$k]` isn't being instantiated I'm just not sure how I need to do it